# Mixing Blade and Twig templates in Laravel

Tags: laravel, twig

I have a Laravel 5.5 project that contains a lot of views in Twig format. In order to support Twig, the project uses the rcrowe/twigbridge package.

This works, but it’s now the only project that I have which uses Twig. Everything else is on Blade. I would like to move this project on to Blade templating, too.

However, I can’t commit a lot of time to this project and do the entire Twig to Blade transition in one go (unless there’s an automatic translator that I should know about?). Therefore it would be helpful to be able to render both Blade and Twig within the same project, at least until the transition is complete. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, I don't think there is, but it sounds to me like what you need is help to do the heavy lifting which I am more than happy to help if your offering a job.

Comment: you should be able to have both, just having the different templates having different extensions like `.blade.php` would be handled by Blade and `.twig` would be handled by twig  .. having twig support should not remove blade support or what ever else you want to use ... but i am not sure if you are going to be using both at the same time in any view/layouts